# Add script after head tag end </head> in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add script after  tag. How can I add this?

Comment: please provide some more info so that any one can help you better.

Comment: I want to add script for home page, category page and product page after </head> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the below code you can add different script for any specific page.

Step1 : Create head-script.phtml and put the below code in the template file.

```
<?php       
        $handles = array_flip($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());
        $catalog_product_view = (isset($handles['catalog_product_view'])) ? TRUE : FALSE;    // for product page
        $category_category_view = (isset($handles['catalog_category_view'])) ? TRUE : FALSE;  // for category page
        $cms_index_index = (isset($handles['cms_index_index'])) ? TRUE : FALSE;   // for Homepage

    if($catalog_product_view ){ ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout(function(){var a=document.createElement("script");
        var b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        a.src=document.location.protocol+"//script.crazyegg.com/pages/scripts/0008/2167.js?"+Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/3600000);
        a.async=true;a.type="text/javascript";b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b)}, 1);
        </script>
    <?php }

    if($category_category_view ){ ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout(function(){var a=document.createElement("script");
        var b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        a.src=document.location.protocol+"//script.crazyegg.com/pages/scripts/0008/2167.js?"+Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/3600000);
        a.async=true;a.type="text/javascript";b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b)}, 1);
        </script>
    <?php } 


    if($cms_index_index ){ ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout(function(){var a=document.createElement("script");
        var b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        a.src=document.location.protocol+"//script.crazyegg.com/pages/scripts/0008/2167.js?"+Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/3600000);
        a.async=true;a.type="text/javascript";b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b)}, 1);
        </script>
    <?php } ?>
```

Step 2: Call the above head-script.phtml below the  tag in layout file.

Answer (score 2):

Add this code in your `local.xml`

```
 <default>
    ..........
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/template" name="afterhead" as="afterhead" template="somefolder/afterhead.phtml" />
        </reference>
    ............... 
    </default>
```

And then call this block in layout (`e.g. 1column.phtml`) file after `</head>` tag

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('afterhead') ?>
```

**Note:** You have to create `afterhead.phtml` file under theme template folder and put the desired content in this file.

If you have no `local.xml` then create it under `app/design/frontend/packagename/themename/layout` and put this code:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/template" name="afterhead" as="afterhead" template="somefolder/afterhead.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean you want to add something right after the `<body>` tag is opened.
Because you should not add anything between `</head>` and `<body>`.
In this case you can add something in the block named `after_body_start`.

For this create your own layout handle in one of your layout files.

```
<my_after_body_start_handle>
    <reference name="after_body_start">
        <block type="core/template" name="my_block" as="my_block" template="path/to/template.phtml" />
    </reference>
</my_after_body_start_handle>
```

Feel free to change the name of the block. Then create the template `path/to/template.phtml` and add your content in there.
Then, to add this in homepage, category page and product page add this in one of your layout file. Can be the same as above.

```
<cms_index_index>
    <update handle="my_after_body_start_handle" />
</cms_index_index>
<catalog_category_default>
    <update handle="my_after_body_start_handle" />
</catalog_category_default>
<catalog_category_layered>
    <update handle="my_after_body_start_handle" />
</catalog_category_layered>
<catalog_product_view>
    <update handle="my_after_body_start_handle" />
</catalog_product_view>
```